# Trying to access https URL using Node.js

Tags: node.js, xml, url, https, ssl-certificate

I am trying to access a XML data set from a HTTPS URL using Node.js. I have used the same code with a different data set that used a HTTP URL and that worked fine.

I have looked into this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssl-root-cas but I don't know how I should go about it.

Here is the code I am using.

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var https = require('https');

function xmlToJson(url, callback) {
    var req = https.get(url, function(res) {
        var xml = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
          xml += chunk;
        });
        res.on('error', function(e) {
          callback(e, null);
        }); 
        res.on('timeout', function(e) {
          callback(e, null);
        }); 
        res.on('end', function() {
          parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
            callback(null, result);
          });
        });
    });
}

var urlTrain = "https://data.dublinked.ie/cgi-bin/rtpi/realtimebusinformation?stopid=7602&format=xml";
xmlToJson(urlTrain, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.err(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.busstopinformation);
        console.log(data.busstopinformation.results);
        console.log(data.busstopinformation.results.result[0]);
        console.log(data.busstopinformation.results.result[0].shortname);
    }
})
```

This is the error I receive in the command line.
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5rqq.png)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead I used the JSON version and used this code instead:

```
var request = require("request")
var url = "https://data.dublinked.ie/cgi-bin/rtpi/realtimebusinformation?stopid=4566&format=json"

request({
    url: url,
    json: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error) {
        console.log(body) // Print the json response
    }
    else{
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

Hopefully someone will find this useful.